# How to dynamically show/hide panel elements with python?

Tags: python, interface, panel

I followed the recommendation of [How to dynamically show/hide panel elements using python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43579/how-to-dynamically-show-hide-panel-elements-using-python)
for an addon and it works fine during script development. But when I install the addon and use the panel an `EnumPropery` which defines the layout seems to have lost the default value. The code is e.g.

```
class ABCK_Panel_with_sectors(bpy.types.Panel):

    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D" # window type panel is displayed in
    bl_region_type = "TOOLS" # region of window panel is displayed in
    bl_label = "Create ABCK objects in sectors 03" # heading of panel

    def draw(self, context) :

        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        col = layout.column()
        #.........................................................
        box = layout.box()
        box.label("General definitions")
        row = box.row()
        row.prop(scene, 'Object_type')
        if scene['Object_type'] == 2: #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!here is the problem
            row = box.row()
            row.prop(scene, 'with_bevels')
            row.prop(scene, 'with_colors')
        #.........................................................
        layout.label("")
        box = layout.box()
        box.label("Math only, no Blender objects")
        box.prop(scene, "Generations")
        box.prop(scene, "all_sectors")
        if scene['all_sectors'] == False:
            box.prop(scene, "Selection_of_sectors")
        row = box.row()  
        row.operator("compute.objects", text = "compute")
        row.operator("print_number_of.objects_sectors", \
            text = "print count math")
        #.........................................................
        layout.label("")
        box = layout.box()
        box.label("Final creation")

        row = box.row()
        row.prop(scene, 'Border_type')
        col = box.column()
        if scene['Border_type'] == Border_sphere:
            col.prop(scene, 'Size_max')
            col.prop(scene, 'Size_min')
        else:
            #col.operator('select.object_for_tesselation')
            col.label("select object for tesselation") 
            col.label("and press 'create objects'")
        row = box.row()
        row.operator("display_all.objects_sectors", \
            text = "create objects")
        if scene['Border_type'] == Border_sphere:
            row.operator("print_number_of.objects_sectors", \
                text = "print count tetrahedrons")
        #.........................................................
        layout.label("")
        row = layout.row()
        box = row.box()
        box.label("Other")
        box = box.row()
        box.operator("delete.objects", text = "delete")
        box.operator("toogle_select_all_visible.objects", \
            text = "toggle selected objects")

        layout.label("")

        row = layout.row()
        tets_on_layer_0 = [ob for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects \
            if (ob.layers[0] and ob.name.startswith("T_"))]
        if len(tets_on_layer_0) == 1:
            row.label(text="1 object generated.", icon='OBJECT_DATA')
        else:
            row.label(text=str((len(tets_on_layer_0))) + \
            " objects generated.", icon='OBJECT_DATA')
```

and I get a 'KeyError':

> 'bpy_struct[key]: key "Object_type" not found.'

What can be done here?

Comment: More code would be helpful, but I would suggest 'if context.scene.object_type == 2:' or whatever you used when you created the property.

Comment: this did not help, now I have shown more code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scene['Object_type']` will refer to a custom property you have added to a scene either by using the Custom Properties panel in the scene properties or by blender automatically creating it as you used `scene['Object_type'] = 2` in your script or the python console.

The proper way to create a new property for your addon to use is by using [`bpy.props`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.props.html).

In your addons `register()` function you define the new property then in `unregister()` you remove it. Within your panel you can then access it with `scene.myprop`

```
import bpy

class LayoutDemoPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the 3D views toolbar region"""
    bl_label = 'Layout Demo'
    bl_idname = 'SCENE_PT_layout_demo'
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene

        row = layout.row()
        row.label('testing')

        if scene.myprop == 2:
            row = layout.row()
            row.label('my property is 2')


def register():
    bpy.types.Scene.myprop = bpy.props.IntProperty(name="My Storage", default=2)
    bpy.utils.register_class(LayoutDemoPanel)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(LayoutDemoPanel)
    del bpy.types.Scene.myprop

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```