# Best way to store options for panels

Tags: python

lets say i have a panel and i want to collapse a part if a bool is False

```
import bpy


class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        # where should i define this bool ? 
        layout.prop(place, "bool")
        if bool is True:
            obj = context.object

            row = layout.row()
            row.label(text="Hello world!", icon='WORLD_DATA')

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Active object is: " + obj.name)



def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Blender 2.8 has sub panels.**

As of blender 2.8 can if `bl_parent_id` is set in a panel it will be appended to the parent panel. Use the usual `'DEFAULT_CLOSED'` in the `bl_options` set to start with panel closed.

This avoids needing to set up some boolean property to open close UI altogether.

Here is a sample file I've been testing for ordering panels.  First panel is defined as a child of the object transform panel. Second panel is a child of first. *Can unregister and re-register with different parent ids to sort sub-panels, which is what I was testing*

[image]
*The two demo sub panels appended to object transform*

```
import bpy
from bl_ui.properties_object import ObjectButtonsPanel, OBJECT_PT_transform

class LayoutDemoPanel(bpy.types.Panel, ObjectButtonsPanel):
    bl_label = "Layout Demo"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_layout"
    bl_parent_id = 'OBJECT_PT_transform'
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        scene = context.scene

        # Create a simple row.
        layout.label(text=" Simple Row:")

        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(scene, "frame_start")

class LayoutDemoPanel2(bpy.types.Panel, ObjectButtonsPanel):
    bl_label = "Layout Demo 2"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_layout2"
    bl_parent_id = 'SCENE_PT_layout'
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        scene = context.scene

        # Create a simple row.
        layout.label(text=" Simple Row:")

        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(scene, "frame_start")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(LayoutDemoPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(LayoutDemoPanel2)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(LayoutDemoPanel2)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(LayoutDemoPanel1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

If you have some logical setting that when set needs more UI [How to dynamically show/hide panel elements using python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43579/how-to-dynamically-show-hide-panel-elements-using-python)

Comment: Cheers. Can still do this the ol' fashioned way too, added link.